# Why is the game series called Resident Evil?

Tags: resident-evil-series

I have always pondered about the title's meaning. Does anybody know anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, in Japan, the game is actually called Biohazard, but when it was brought to the US, there was concerns that they would never be able to get the name trademarked, so they decided to go for something else. They held an internal contest to see what the new name should be, and the name *Resident Evil* was chosen. Supposedly, it was supposed to be a play on the fact that the first game takes place in a mansion.

[Source](http://www.gamesradar.com/gr-asks-why-was-biohazard-renamed-resident-evil/)

Comment: Further insight: If you translate Resident Evil from english to japanese, you get ["Baiohazādo"](https://www.google.com/search?q=resident+evil+in+japanese+to+engish&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=japan+translation+of+resident+evil).

Comment: Very interesting!